# Getting the permanent address of an ethernet device

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the permanent address of an ethernet device in Python(3).

I've looked at various ways to do this:

- Here's [netifaces](https://github.com/al45tair/netifaces), a Python library that can retrieve MAC addresses. Sadly, it's not able to fetch the permanent address of a device. so it can be overwritten
- Here's [python-ethtool](https://github.com/fedora-python/python-ethtool). This does what I want, but it's deprecated and won't run with Python3 on the specific machine I'm developing for.
- Then of course, I could just call `ethtool -P` from the command line (within Python, using subprocess) and read the output.

I've looked at the code for [ethtool](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/core/ethtool.c), and the information I need seems to live in a field of struct dev called perm_addr:

```
static int ethtool_get_perm_addr(struct net_device *dev, void __user *useraddr)
{
    struct ethtool_perm_addr epaddr;

    if (copy_from_user(&epaddr, useraddr, sizeof(epaddr)))
        return -EFAULT;

    if (epaddr.size < dev->addr_len)
        return -ETOOSMALL;
    epaddr.size = dev->addr_len;

    if (copy_to_user(useraddr, &epaddr, sizeof(epaddr)))
        return -EFAULT;
    useraddr += sizeof(epaddr);
    if (copy_to_user(useraddr, dev->perm_addr, epaddr.size))
        return -EFAULT;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I access this information in Python? I'd prefer an all Python solution over opening a subprocess and calling ethtool.

Comment: One thing you could do is call `ethtool` from the command-line within python (with the  help of the `subprocess` module) if that works for you

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy: I know that and I have mentioned it in my question. Probably haven't made it clear enoug (see the edit).

Comment: Maybe this kind of info is available through /sys/class/net/ these days?

Comment: If the info hadn't been available from /sys/class/net/ - then other possibilities I could think of would include using Python FFI, or writing a Python binding in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available through the file `/sys/class/net/<iface>/address`.  The file `/sys/class/net/<iface>/addr_assign_type` indicates the type of address.

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net, and look for 'permanent' in that document.

Comment: Cheers @Roadowl :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#address named by userspace:
    ip a | egrep -A1 ${IFACE}:
    egrep -H . /sys/class/net/*/addr_assign_type /sys/class/net/*/address | egrep ${IFACE}/
#permanent address:
    ethtool -P ${IFACE} | egrep -i permanent
    egrep -H . /sys/class/net/${IFACE}/bonding_slave/perm_hwaddr
    egrep -H "Slave Interface:|Permanent HW addr:" /proc/net/bonding/storage | egrep -A1 "${IFACE}\$"
    #sles/centos: hwinfo --network | egrep " Permanent HW Address|SysFS ID" | egrep -A1 "${IFACE}\$"
```